# Unable to create a mysql client inside a docker container: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, docker, terminal

I am trying to create a mysql client inside of a docker container, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[full terminal screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wATEc.png)

Even after setting the password to root@localhost, I still get the same response (as seen in the image).

Comment: You need to configure it with an host parameter. As far as I remember, authentication with a socket does not work well inside a container so you need to authentify via an IP (smthg like `-h 127.0.0.1`).

Comment: can you send your docker-compose file?

Comment: this is an example to create a docker container very simple. send your docker-compose content to see better. docker run -itd --name test -p 3380:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123333 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=test -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=123123 mysql:8.0.21